# Temporarily blocked in specific facebook query

Tags: facebook

I am migrating some scripts that get public events from Graph API. I try to get the events for some regions in Spain, but I get blocked. I use this query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?access_token={0}&q={1}&type=event
```

This script runs periodically, and it loops through a list of region names each time (the q parameter). I have checked API limits, but the message I get is this one:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "You have been temporarily blocked from performing this action.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 368
  }
}
```

I have tried to create a new app/account and it works, but it starts to give me the same error after some iterations.

The data is used in a research project, and I think I am missing something in terms of limits.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: i am guessing you are using too many api calls. reduce the number of calls.

Comment: Creating new accounts are against Facebook policy so if you don't want to get banned that is not a good idea. And scraping Facebook is not a good idea

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try to reduce the number of requests.

I don't know why is such a bad idea to scrap Facebook. The gathered data is used for a research project that tries to prevent possible incidents in a electrical network depending on the demand. Taking into account that this information is produced by Facebook users, not by Facebook itself, I don't know why they use such restrictive policies.

Comment: When a user signs up he/she agrees to Facebook's policies. When a developer signs up, he/she agrees to Facebook's policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to reduce drastically the number of requests I was launching, and now I am able again to make API calls to look for events.

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: How long did your block last?